# Parameter substitution for a SQLite with multiple “IN” clause

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to execute the below query in SQLite from Python.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
names = ['name1','name2']
ids = ['id1','id2']
query = 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT_DETAILS WHERE NAME IN (%s)' % ','.join('?'*len(names)) + ' AND ID IN (%s)' % ','.join('?'*len(ids))
c.execute(query,(names, ids))
conn.close()
```

When I execute the above code, I am getting this below error.

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 2 supplied.
```

I am able to execute the query with single IN clause in the query as shown below.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
names = ['name1','name2']
query = 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT_DETAILS WHERE NAME IN (%s)' % ','.join('?'*len(names))
c.execute(query,names)
conn.close()
```

I would like to know, how to substitute values, If I use multiple IN clause in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of `?`s in the SQL query needs to match the number of items in the parameters tuple. In your first example there are two items in the tuple: `names` and `ids`. But there are four question marks. Try `tuple(names) + tuple(ids)`, or define the variables as tuples using round brackets and then just use `names + ids`.

In the second example it's one tuple `names` containing two names, hence it works.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to add STATUS=? to the where condition in the query, how should I substitute the values.

Comment: Assuming the status is at the end of the SQL, then `tuple(names) + tuple(ids) + (status,)`.